# difficulty showing different marker colors in php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have difficulty in showing different marker colors. this marker color difference is based on a value from the database.

this is coding to bring up maps and markers

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY"
  type="text/javascript">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function init(){
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.320795, 112.731386),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    <?php foreach($get_data->result() as $row) {
      $nilai = $row->nilai;
      if($nilai >= 0 && $nilai <=50) {?>
        var icons = {
          info: {
            icon: '<?php echo base_url("assets/marker_merah.png");?>'
          }
        };
      <?php }elseif($nilai >= 51 && $nilai <=69){ ?>
        var icons = {
          info: {
            icon: '<?php echo base_url("assets/marker_hijau.png");?>'
          }
        };
      <?php }elseif($nilai >= 70) { ?>
        var icons = {
          info: {
            icon: '<?php echo base_url("assets/marker_biru.png");?>'
          }
        };
      <?php }
    } ?>

    var features = [
    <?php foreach($get_data->result() as $row){ ?>
      {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row->lat;?>,<?php echo $row->long;?>),
        type: 'info',
        title : '<?php echo $row->nama;?>'
      },
    <?php } ?>
    ];

    // Create markers.
    features.forEach(function(feature) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
        title: feature.title,
        map: map
      });
    });
  }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
```

I want to bring up red markers for values 0-50, green for values 51-69, and blue for values 70 and above.

after I run the code above, I find all markers are only green, and red and blue markers do not appear.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You execute the following loop `<?php foreach($get_data->result() as $row) {` two times in your code.

The first time it will generate in JavaScript something similar to

```
var icons = {
   info: {
        icon: 'assets/marker_hijau.png'
   }
};

var icons = {
    info: {
        icon: 'assets/marker_merah.png>'
    }
};

var icons = {
    info: {
        icon: 'assets/marker_biru.png>'
    }
};

var icons = {
    info: {
        icon: 'assets/marker_merah.png>'
    }
};
```

So, you just redefine the same variable multiple times and clearly the JavaScript will use the last value that you assigned to `icons` variable.

The second loop  creates an array structure and I would suggest put icon initialization in the second loop as well, so you can define icon property of each feature and use it later in JavaScript.

I would rewrite your code to something similar to

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"
  type="text/javascript">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function init(){
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.320795, 112.731386),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var features = [
    <?php foreach($get_data->result() as $row) { 
      $nilai = $row->nilai; ?>
      {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row->lat;?>,<?php echo $row->long;?>),
        type: 'info',
        <?php if($nilai >= 0 && $nilai <=50) {?>
            icon: '<?php echo base_url("assets/marker_merah.png");?>',
        <?php } elseif($nilai >= 51 && $nilai <=69) { ?>
            icon: '<?php echo base_url("assets/marker_hijau.png");?>',
        <?php } elseif($nilai >= 70) { ?>
            icon: '<?php echo base_url("assets/marker_biru.png");?>',
        <?php } ?>
        title : '<?php echo $row->nama;?>'
      },
    <?php } ?>
    ];

    // Create markers.
    features.forEach(function(feature) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: feature.icon,
        title: feature.title,
        map: map
      });
    });
  }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Xenomena is right, you're js is replace each other.. my guessing you get the code from

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers
You must careful see there is multidimensional array there.

```
     var icons = {
      parking: {
        icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
      },
      library: {
        icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
      },
      info: {
        icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
      }
    };
```

So, my answer is :

```
        var icons = {
      info1: {
        icon: 'icons/blue.png'
      },
      info2: {
        icon: 'icons/white.png'
      },
      info3: {
        icon: 'icons/red.png'
      }
    };
```

That's make mltidimensional array for icon, then i make my own latlong data in array get_lang, and nilai data in array get_data :

```
foreach($get_lat as $i=>$row){ ?>
  {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row[0];?>,<?php echo $row[1];?>),
<?php
  if($get_data[$i] <50) {?>
    type: 'info1',
  <?php } elseif ($get_data[$i] >= 51 && $get_data[$i] <=69){ ?>
    type: 'info2',
  <?php } else { ?>
    type: 'info3',
  <?php } ?>
    title : "<?php echo $row[0];?>"
  },
<?php } ?>
];
```

Suggestion, next time when you post you're code, you need post you're sample input as well.

The full works code :

https://pastebin.com/dWj5wjTE

Hope this help.